# Sort files by modification time

Tags: find, ls, wildcards, sort, timestamps

I've seen many questions and answers here using a construction along the lines of

```
list_dir=`ls -t /path/to/dir/`
for i in $list_dir; do
```

or

```
ls -t | while read i; do
```

Now, I know that you [shouldn't use ls in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) because it breaks easily; but I can't find a better way of operating on files in order from last-modified to most-recently-modified (or vice versa).

I can use something like:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | while read i; do...
```

...but this will still break with any files that have newlines in their names, and is much uglier to boot. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Don't use ls in scripts" is a problem with POSIX ls "only"; for GNU ls see `--quoting-style=`.

GNU sort solves the problem with `--zero-terminated`.

If it must be compatible then you could use `find ... -exec` for passing one file name at a time to a script which does the escaping. If at least bash is available:

```
start cmd:> testfunc () { echo "${1//$'\n'/\n}"; }
start cmd:> testfunc a$'\n'b
a\nb
```

Comment: Ahh, `--zero-terminated` - thank you for that, I wish I could give you even more points!

Comment: ...OK, I'm a little confused by `info ls`: if I wanted a bulletproof script with ls, which `--quoting-style` should I use?

Comment: @evilsoup I think `--quoting-style=escape` is the way to choose.

Comment: Now, to create some files with newlines in their names to test it :P

Comment: @evilsoup `touch filename`. You can simply press Enter after " or ' (and close the quotes in one of the following lines). Or do this: `touch a$'\n'b` (in bash)

Comment: About GNU `ls` : you can also use `-Q` to double quote filenames that can have spaces.

Comment: Also: I stumble upon a extreme case where ever GNU `ls` `--quoting-style` fail (for parsing purposea) because it quote filenames only: when you have a space in a group name. Ok, its a very strage case, but it appen in cygwin bash shell, here you have group names like `Domain Users`.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way by far is to use zsh. The [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `om` sorts matches in reverse chronological order; use `Om` for chronological order.

```
for x in /path/to/dir/*(Nom); do …
```

The `N` glob qualifier causes the pattern to expand to an empty list if the directory is empty. Make this `*(DNom)` to match dot files.

Comment: Dang, this is the first time I've been tempted to bother looking at other shells - that's very nice.